# Dremel SQL: CASE WHEN 2 conditions return too many records

Tags: sql, dremel

I would like to return a rows that have a column which values are between 80 and 91.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN ROUND((offer_percent*100),1) > 90 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) AS MoreThan90,
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN 80 < ROUND((offer_percent*100),1) < 91 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) AS LessThan90
FROM
  approval_state
WHERE
  id IN ($id)
```

and the output is:

```
MoreThan90 | LessThan90
1            10
```

I'm expecting then LessThan90 to return only 2 records but it returns 10, which is the total number of records in the table.

Any idea how I can 2 records for LessThan90 only?

Thanks

Comment: for a correct coverage of the range should be  WHEN ROUND((offer_percent*100),1) <= 90  or for a correct coverage of the range should be  WHEN  ROUND((offer_percent*100),1) between 80 and  90

Comment: `80 < ROUND((offer_percent*100),1) < 91` is not "between 80 and 91". `80 > ROUND((offer_percent*100),1) < 91` or `ROUND((offer_percent*100),1) BETWEEN 79 and 90` is.

Comment: @HoneyBadger thanks!  *80 > ROUND((offer_percent*100),1) < 91*   doesnt work though.     *ROUND((offer_percent*100),1) BETWEEN 79 and 90* works

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, there is an `and` missing in the first statement. For reference, it should have been  `80 < ROUND((offer_percent*100),1) AND ROUND((offer_percent*100),1) < 91`. `BETWEEN` is definitely easier to read.

Comment: @HoneyBadger gotcha thanks!